# Getting coordinates of an image map with a mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I have an html image map and I want to get the coordinates when a user clicks on the map.

**Is there a way to retrieve the map coordinates with a mouse click on the map?**

Comment: Do you want to get the map x and y position or the coords property value of the area tag on which click has been made

Comment: I want to get the coordinates of were the click has been made and submitted on the image map in order to store them in my database and show them later on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JQuery library and do the following:

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
        e.pageX;
              e.pageY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. But using only javascript could be very complex.

If you can you need to implement jquery and then check [this link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/jquery-and-html-image-maps.html).

If you are talking about a real map image (like google maps or something) once you get the mouse coordinates simply multiply by the map scale. :)

Comment: No this is not a real map image of the world or something, it is a restaurant plan view in which users will be able to book a table by clicking on the image.