# Dynamic map with php

Tags: php, dynamic, dictionary

First of all, please excuse me for my bad english!:)

Im developing several mods for a phpbb3 forum, and right know i need something i have never did before. Im needing to display a custom map, but at the same time i need to show in that map as little points the name of certain users of the forums in certain locations. (its a "fixed" pic, i dont need to create it dinamically or nothing)

The place of each locations will be "fixed" in the map too, and the only interaction thing i need with the map is a tool-tip text with the name of the user that is being pointed

The users will appear in the position that corresponds with certain forum id, so in fact i retrieve each user location from a table in a database, and the location would be only a number.. and i need to map that numbers to locations in the map.

What sort of things should i learn in order to do this task? If you can give me some links i would be very grateful!!

Comment: You might look into the [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

Comment: You seem to understand the basic concepts already, like looking things up in a database. If you could make your question more specific then you might get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an arbitary map (like a map of a game world), you need a manual list of x-y map grid/pixel location mapped to a named location. This can be represented as 2D array, but if you only want a single ID, then you can use a 1D mapping function e.g. id = y * width + x;

Once every location has an x-y location, you can then use img coordinates with methods used in [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825216/getting-coordinates-of-an-image-map-with-a-mouse-click) to correctly position your "little points" `<div>` or `<spans>` etc. over the map image. If you need more fancy stuff, use Flash. The tool tip stuff is no more than simple javascript+css display attribute manipulation. Try googling for "javascript tooltips".

Answer (score 0):

Commonly used for this task is the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html).

It is easy to integrate, especially if you already have latitude/longitude coordinates for what you need to show on the map.  (If you don't, you can use Google's geocoding web service to handle that for you.)

The mapping is all done client-side in JavaScript.  Most often, you will need to write a simple web service in PHP that serves up JSON (or XML, or something else) to your JavaScript program with AJAX, so that you can pass the necessary data on to the Google Map for display.